# How to maximize loss function in Keras

Tags: optimization, keras, deep-learning

In Keras, the optimizer (default ones) minimizes the loss function by default. Is there any way I can make the optimizer maximize the loss function?

Comment: Multiply by -1 and minimize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to maximise a loss function while trying to minimise it is to multiply the loss by -1, i.e.

```
new_loss = -loss
```

Comment: how do you deal with minimize negative score but with 0 loss produced?

Comment: either your network has converged or you need to choose a different loss function, perhaps.

Comment: how do you deal with negative loss values.

Comment: @user3352632 you don't let the network do its thing.

Comment: @learner: Let us consider that loss := 10, then applying your formula: new_loss := -10. Now keras have to handle a negative loss value. Does this work?

Comment: @user3352632 It works, provided the network calculates the gradient with respect to `new_loss`.